# Как в pandas преобразовать строки в столбцы (PIVOT) по заданным элементам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot

При решении статистической задачки получаю таблицу CSV с примерно такими данными:

```
expr  Therapy
100   A
98    B
87    C
97    D
102   C
96    B
92    D
88    A
```

Преобразовываю в dataframe, чтобы потом оттуда делать графики через matplotlib. Но перед этим мне надо посчитать статистические показатели для четырех выборок (A, B, C, D). Можно ли в pandas преобразовать исходную структуру таблицы и получить такую?

```
A   B   C   D
100 98  87  97
88  96  102 92
```

Или проще сначала прочитать csv в переменную, сделать словарь, в нем посчитать все показатели (медиану, внутригрупповой квадрат и т.п.), а потом уже отправлять все в dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [7]: res = (df.assign(idx=df.groupby('Therapy').cumcount())
                 .pivot_table(index='idx', columns='Therapy', 
                              values='expr', aggfunc='sum'))

In [8]: res
Out[8]:
Therapy    A   B    C   D
idx
0        100  98   87  97
1         88  96  102  92
```

Пошагово:

для того чтобы воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) нам понадобятся значения, которые будут выступать в качестве индекса строк в результирующей выборке - создаем "на лету" новый столбец `idx`:

```
In [10]: df.assign(idx=df.groupby('Therapy').cumcount())
Out[10]:
   expr Therapy  idx
0   100       A    0
1    98       B    0
2    87       C    0
3    97       D    0
4   102       C    1
5    96       B    1
6    92       D    1
7    88       A    1
```

теперь можно воспользоваться `pivot_table()`:

```
In [11]: df.assign(idx=df.groupby('Therapy').cumcount()).pivot_table(index='idx', columns='Therapy', values='expr', aggfunc='sum')
Out[11]:
Therapy    A   B    C   D
idx
0        100  98   87  97
1         88  96  102  92
```

Comment: А можно еще пару комментариев о том, как это работает?

Comment: @Viktorov, дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения )

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо за два варианта. Оба работают, но понятны мне не до конца. Есть в чем разобраться! )

Comment: @Burtsev, пожалуйста! Если будут вопросы задавайте их на SO :)

Answer (score 4):

Для того, чтобы расчитать различные статистики с группировкой по `Therapy` необязательно разворачивать DataFrame:

```
In [20]: df.groupby('Therapy')['expr'].agg(['median', 'sum', 'std'])
Out[20]:
         median  sum        std
Therapy
A          94.0  188   8.485281
B          97.0  194   1.414214
C          94.5  189  10.606602
D          94.5  189   3.535534
```